# Angular 2 - How can I get an unparsed version of my current route

Tags: angular, routes

I want an unparsed version of my current route

ie:  `dashboard/:id`

I dont want the `id` part shown as a number.

this is what im on

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-breadcrumb": "^0.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
```

tried looking through `Router`, and `ActivatedRoute` and cannot find it..

```
  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {

    console.log(this.activatedRoute.routeConfig.path)
  }
```

`Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:54:2 caused by: Cannot read property 'path' of null`

Comment: Could you upload your routes configuration? And in what component you are having that error? @hamobi

Answer (score 0):

From `ActivatedRoute` you could access `Route`, then use the `path` value to get the unparsed route.

Code on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VLwHzkQeRRhUCndoVjKk?p=preview)

Comment: i'm getting an error.. look above.  my routeconfig is null